# Get form elements and store into an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the input elements in a form using JavaScript. Then I am trying to organize it by putting it into an array by its name attribute. Can anyone please help?

```
function getFields(formName, attr){
    var form=document.getElementById(formName);
    var fields=form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var fieldCount=fields.length-1;
    var fieldNames=[];
    for(var a in fieldCount){
        fieldNames[a]=fields[a].getAttribute(attr)
    }
    return fieldNames[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already in an associated array via the  DOM object:

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.elements['myInputName'] //Returns <input name="myInputName">

form.elements['myInputName'].value //Returns the value
```

Comment: Then why does it keep saying "undefined" when I run it?

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit. It returns the input object, not the value. If it's still null make sure your <script> tag is defined after the form element in your page otherwise it's DOM object isn't ready when your script is. Alternatively use jQuery's "ready" function.